# Preg_replace doesn't work in laravel controller

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, indexing, preg-match

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class SiteController extends Controller{
    public $posts = [
        1 => [
            'title'  => 'Тайтл страницы 1',
            'author' => 'Автор страницы 1',
            'dated'   => 'Дата публикации страницы 1',
            'teaser' => 'Короткое описание страницы 1',
            'text'   => 'Полный текст страницы 1',
        ],
        2 => [
            'title'  => 'Тайтл страницы 2',
            'author' => 'Автор страницы 2',
            'dated'   => 'Дата публикации страницы 2',
            'teaser' => 'Короткое описание страницы 2',
            'text'   => 'Полный текст страницы 2',
        ],
        3 => [
            'title'  => 'Тайтл страницы 3',
            'author' => 'Автор страницы 3',
            'dated'   => 'Дата публикации страницы 3',
            'teaser' => 'Короткое описание страницы 3',
            'text'   => 'Полный текст страницы 3',
        ],
        4 => [
            'title'  => 'Тайтл страницы 4',
            'author' => 'Автор страницы 4',
            'dated'   => 'Дата публикации страницы 4',
            'teaser' => 'Короткое описание страницы 4',
            'text'   => 'Полный текст страницы 4',
        ],
        5 => [
            'title'  => 'Тайтл страницы 5',
            'author' => 'Автор страницы 5',
            'dated'   => 'Дата публикации страницы 5',
            'teaser' => 'Короткое описание страницы 5',
            'text'   => 'Полный текст страницы 5',
        ]
    ];
    public function showOne($id){
        $length = count($this->posts);
        if(preg_match("#[1-$length]#", $id))
            return view('page', ['arr' => [$this->posts[$id]], 'l' => $length]);
        else
            return view('404');
    }
}
```

I have 5 posts which I want to get by passing get parameter in the url. I'm checking whether value is in range of array of posts. However, preg_replace doesn't work for some reason, I checked the $length value through var_dump and it gives me the exact value I need, which is 5. For example, if I pass 20 as $id parameter in url, preg_replace still returns true and gives me a mistake of offset.

Comment: Wouldn't [`array_key_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-key-exists.php) be a much better fit for this?

Comment: Thanks. I am used to putting everything in regular expressions since they can check everything. Looks like not, though